# S3 url rewrite with or without cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, react-router, amazon-cloudfront

We store multiple micro react projects on a single S3 buckets like this:

http://s3/auth/
http://s3/user_profile/
http://s3/whatever/

Every single url in this case a directory where we host an index.html with the react project with a react router.

The problem is, we would like to hit the auth project with the http://s3/auth/login not just with the http://s3/auth

Is there any way to get every query under /auth in the /auth root?

Comment: this could be a few things. 1) you don't properly set a 404 redirect in AWS console. 2) your webpack.config file doesn't properly set your publicPath, 3) you dont properly set the `__webpack_public_path__` in your application

Comment: How can I set multiple 404 redirects in a single bucket?

Comment: not that i know of, its abit hard trying to help you out, i have very little context as to what your project looks like. Is there any reason you have multiple react apps instead of just one wraps all your pages?, that way you can use react router properly.

Comment: Sure, in this case, all of them is nicely separated, and releasable one-by-one.